# Inserting rows from excel into mysql throws JDBC exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-poi

[After taking help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430895/poi-reading-excel-strings-as-numeric) for reading excel date values correctly, I am faced with another issue that I am stumped with. The cell quotes for VARCHAR columns is lost when inserting the excel row.

For instance, I read a row into List like

[1,ahsan, 2013-12-12]

Then when forming the query and executing the SQL statement I am given `MySQLSyntaxException`. How do I retain (or for that matter add single quotes for the data fetched) when using insert statement. Following is the code I am using to form query,

```
Statement stmt = null;
String qry = "insert into "+ fieldValue + " (";
for (int i=0; i<sheetColumnNames.size(); i++ ) {

    if (i == (sheetColumnNames.size() -1)) {
        qry +=  sheetColumnNames.get(i) +")";
    }
    else
    {
        qry +=  sheetColumnNames.get(i) +",";
     }              }
qry += " values " ;
qry += "(";
// This code is in a Row loop                  
for (int i=0; i<rowSet.size(); i++) { 
   if (i == (rowSet.size() -1)) 
   {
       if ((row.getRowNum()+1)==(sheet.getLastRowNum()+1))
       {    
        qry +=  rowSet.get(i) +")";
       }
       else
       {
        qry +=  rowSet.get(i) +"),";
       }
    }
    else
    {


        qry +=  rowSet.get(i) +",";
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using **Prepared Statements**, then MySQL/JDBC can handle it for you.

Also currently your database is vulnerable to SQL injection.

**EDIT:** Also performance should be way better (not sure if noticable though), because you are re-using the statement assuming there are multiple rows in an Excel file.